# Problem with the hover effect in css

Tags: css

check this simple code: http://jsfiddle.net/DECPY/ . As you can see when you hover the menu item a gray backgroud apear, but, no behind the menu icon. How can i put the color backgroud behind the image when the mouse pass over?

This is an image that explains evrythink: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code a little. I moved `home-ico` class to `a` link. And changed appropriate styles. See it [here](http://jsbin.com/unekaz/3/edit#javascript,html,live).

Answer (score 1):

You can do the folowing:

replace

```
div#vertmenu ul li.home-ico {...}
```

with:

```
.home-ico img {
    margin: 0 5px -2px 0;
}
```

And change yor html like this:

```
<div id="vertmenu"> 
    <ul>
        <li class="home-ico">
            <a href="#" tabindex="1">
                <img border="0" src="http://www.benyboatti.com/images/home-icon.png"/>
                Home
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note: it works even in IE6.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DECPY/1/)